# Inserting and filtering text with SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, text, insert

I have an asp.net project that I am trying to insert words one by one out of text into my SQL Server database. Insert works well however I would like to filter some words

[image]

and delete from database by using table named filter that I have already created.

But for this part (filtering) of my code, I get an error

> The connection string property has not been initialized

Code:

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        using (con) {
            con.Open();

            foreach (var item in results) { // here trying to insert word its id and some other information but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
                id++;
                string w = item.Word.ToString();

                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", item.Word);
                cmd.CommandText= "INSERT INTO word(id, word, sid, frequency, weight, f) VALUES (@id, @word, 0, 0, 0, 0) ";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();               

            SqlCommand cmf = con.CreateCommand();
            cmf.CommandText = "delete from word where word.word in (select filter.word from filter)";

            cmf.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't reuse the same SqlConnection instance. Create another one instead or execute sql in one using statement.

Comment: I have changed the cmd to cmf for the second instance but I get the same error and error resource is this line. Line 75:      con.Open();

Comment: Did you try to use new SqlConnection each time like using(var conn = new SqlConnection(cs)) ?